# Surface area and the Volume of a spiked icosahedron by using integration

Tags: integration, volume, solid-geometry, platonic-solids

I am doing my math project on the properties of a spiked icosahedron. I already calculated the surface area and the volume through other methods, but the teacher asked me to find a generic formula for the properties through integration as well. The model is formed of $20$ identical pyramids, without a base, with the side length of $8.6$cm Each of the pyramids is made of three folded flaps, which have been folded of $15x15$ cm squares.

So I am stuck on the formula..

Comment: Just a note, it's possible your icosahedron is not just "spiked" but actually [stellated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stellation). There are 59 [inequivalent ways](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stellated_icosahedron#Table_of_the_fifty-nine_icosahedra) to stellate an icosahedron. (If you are just adding pyramids to faces, this is called [cumulation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Cumulation.html).

Comment: Since nobody else seems to be biting, a few questions. 1) You don't really want/have to find the volume through *integration*, do you? For an individual pyramid it's reasonable, but for something complicated like an icosahedron even it's just awful. 2) Just to make sure, these are "uniform" pyramids, all edges the same length? And all you know about the length is that it's been measured to be about 8.6 cm, nothing exact?